# Is there any manager for Hortonwork Data platform on Windows Platform

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform, hue

Hi I am newbie to Hortonworks Data Platform. I have installed HDP2.4 on Windows Server 2012 R2. As of now i am running my Pig jobs on Command Prompt but I want to know is there any Editors like HUE in Cloudera and any Hortons Manager like cloudera Manager. I am working on Windows OS so I think Ambari of Hortonworks also not support. Please Help me any in this Kind.

Answer (score 1):

Like cloudera manager , for horton works ambari-service is there but it works only in ubuntu/linux based platforms (or) cent os not  in windows.